# Can I use Passportjs to authenticate only certain google users?

Tags: javascript, passport.js

So i am curious in making a intranet type application that allows my users to authenticate via google. I am using PassportJS to link them but im wondering if you can allow only certain users (that i choose) to be authenticated.

I was thinking i can use a google group or something and only allow that group to pass authentication?....I'm not sure. If someone can help me out thatd be cool

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. If you're using `passport-google-oauth` for example, I would point you to this code example:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/blob/287d53b/examples/oauth2/app.js#L37

In the `verify` function, after passport has verified the incoming user's google account, you can make your own decision, for example calling a google API to check if that user is part of a specific google group.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    // Your custom group membership checking goes here
    checkGroupMembership(profile, function(err, isMember) {
      if (isMember) {
        done(null, profile);
      } else {
        done(new Error('Not part of google group!'));
      }
    });
  }
));
```